# Some items in collections are not displayed in collection lists and are not included when calculating strength count

Tags: dspace

Environment:

- DSpace 5.5
- XMLUI
- CentoOS7

Some items in collection are:

- not displayed in collection lists
- not included when calculating strength count.

I've tried re-indexing w/ `index-authority -b -s`, with no result.

It seems that the problem lies with dc.contributor.author with a dspace generated uid, for example *Surname, Name::d141b689-acec-4c97-a726-d4b9c651a805::600*

What seems to work is to go to edit a problematic record (csv metadata edit)

- delete author
- commit changes
- edit metadata and add the author back
- commit changes

The above procedure results in the item being listed and included in strength count.

My questions is, apart from deleting and re-adding the author, is there something I can do to make dspace aware of all ignored records and properly display them?

Answer (score 0):

try
./dspace index-authority -f
to reindex all items
and check (and post) the /log/dspace.log.2022-xx-yy